# ng-repeat PHP variables

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

I have a problem with ng-repeat and ng-init. It doens'nt show me the content nor the ID when i ask for them in my code (project.content). But it doesn't show the text itself either. So somewhere something is going wrong. Note that I use other open and close tags for angular as default.

Appareantly Angular sees something different in the code as the browser or I do, as I recieve this console error:

> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.12/$parse/ueoe?p0=projects%20%3D%20%7B

```
<table ng-init="projects = {" id":"1","content":"testtesttest"}="" "="">
```

How can I get this to work?

HTML code:

```
<div ng-app="overviewApp">
    <table  ng-init="projects = <?=json_encode($projects)?> ">
        <tr ng-repeat="project in projects">
            <td>[{[project.content]}]</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Looks like this when in browser source code:

```
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="content-section">
                <div ng-app="overviewApp">
<table  ng-init="projects = {"id":1,"content":"TestTestTest"} ">
    <tr ng-repeat="project in projects">
        <td>[{[project.content]}]</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot parse it because it is seeing double quotes inside double quotes. Try using single quotes.

```
<table  ng-init='projects = <?=json_encode($projects)?> '>
```

Also you must ensure that `projects` is in array format like so:

```
ng-init='projects = [{"id":1,"content":"TestTestTest"}]'
```

Finally, since you are using a custom interpolate providers `{[{` and `}]}`, you must define that in your config:

```
app.config(['$interpolateProvider', function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[{[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']}]');
}]);
```

See it working: [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/cfUexjaS0S3YJys0kyH7?p=preview)

Alternatively, instead of using interpolation markup, I would recommend using the `ng-bind` directive like so:

```
<td><span ng-bind="project.content"></span></td>
```

See a [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/rliA4PkEd6qEJJeQl8Yk?p=preview).

NOTE: The AngularJS [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) recommends using a controller over the `ng-init` directive to initialize values on a scope.

Comment: Allright, that works! But I still don't get any output. But, the error is gone!

Comment: You need two curly braces around your output variable.

Comment: I'm sorry, the demo doensn't work. The curly braces won't work for me cause I changed the Angular opening tags to [{[. I'm using it in combination with Blade (Laravel) which uses the same {{

Comment: I do get output now, but the fun part... it shows the var I'm asking for. Eg, on the screen I see this:  [{[project.content]}]

Comment: I updated the DEMO with custom opening/closing tags.